# すべて見る目 vs すべてを見る目 vs すべての見る目

Tags: nuances, particles

So to say "all seeing eye" in Japanese, すべて見る目 is all good as far as I know, but I've occasionally run into it with wo「を」 and no「の」. What are the nuances of saying it with these particles, compared to without? I think I would choose wo before no if I want to describe an eye that sees everything, would that make sense or is it all extremely similar? I'm still new to phrasing the same thing in different ways.

Comment: By the way if you mean something like a pyramid eye thing, I think it'll be すべてを見通す目.

Answer (score 1):

These can be parsed as:

[すべて見る]目, relative clause + noun

[すべて**を**見る]目, same thing, but this time すべて is treated as a noun

[すべて**の**][見る目], is a bit more interesting because now 見る目 is treated as a noun phrase modified by another noun

Translating the third one into English gives a very awkward phrase, but it might be more natural-sounding in Japanese.